# why one would use xargs without params?

Tags: shell, xargs

I'm debugging a complex shell script and there is next code:

```
echo $data | xargs -n1 | sort -u | sed 's/.*/%&%/' | xargs | sed 's/ /,/g;s/%/"/g'`
```

what use may have xargs without any command here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xargs` with no command uses its default command, `echo`. This can be used to perform basic text-processing of `xargs`’s input.

Here it’s used first to output one word per line, and then to merge lines:

```
xargs -n1
```

takes its input, splits it up into words, and outputs one word per line;

```
sort -u
```

sorts the lines;

```
sed 's/.*/%&%/'
```

wraps each line with `%` symbols;

```
xargs
```

puts everything back into a single line, separated by spaces; finally

```
sed 's/ /,/g;s/%/"/g'
```

replaces all the spaces with commas and the `%` symbols with double quotes.

So ultimately the purpose of the series of commands is to turn whitespace-separated input into sorted comma-separated, quoted output.